# Change dimension of a dateframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: This is my dataframe]

I have a dataframe with a MultiIndex and dimensions 18 x 1. I want to get a dataframe with dimensions 6 x 3 with the airline names as row index and the sentiments negative, neutral and positive as column names. What is the quickest way to do that?

I have a data example here:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['airline_1', 'airline_2', 'airline_3','airline_4', 'airline_5', 'airline_6'],
                                  ['negative', 'neutral', 'positive']],
                                 names=['airline', 'sentiment'])
col = ['test']
df = pd.DataFrame('-',idx,col)
test = []
for i in range(18):
    test.append(i)
df['value'] = test
df = df.drop('test', axis = 1)
```

Comment: can you share a minimum amout of data to work with?

Comment: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['airline_1', 'airline_2', 'airline_3','airline_4', 'airline_5', 'airline_6'],
                                  ['negative', 'neutral', 'positive']],
                                 names=['airline', 'sentiment'])
col = ['test']
df = pd.DataFrame('-',idx,col)
test = []
for i in range(18):
    test.append(i)
df['value'] = test
df = df.drop('test', axis = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple once you know the method :
Just `df.unstack()` will get you there :)

To get rid of the MultiIndex as columns, and just keep the sentiment scores, do :

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: `df['airline_sentiment'].unstack()` or `df.squeeze().unstack()`